# Parsing a data table from text files

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I'm a chemist working with quantum chemistry and my software generates a large output. Part of this output is the molecular orbital composition.
Here is a snip:

```
------------------
MOLECULAR ORBITALS
------------------
                      0         1         2         3         4         5   
                 -10.15161  -0.69244  -0.39172  -0.39172  -0.39172   0.05029
                   2.00000   2.00000   2.00000   2.00000   2.00000   0.00000
                  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------
  0C   1s         0.466772 -0.095648  0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000  0.051744
  0C   2s         0.608599 -0.202428  0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000  0.113737
  0C   3s         0.034954  0.321132 -0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 -0.300805
  0C   4s        -0.014530  0.330414  0.000001  0.000002 -0.000001  0.208530
  0C   5s         0.022640  0.091859  0.000000 -0.000002  0.000000 -4.760727
  0C   1pz       -0.000000 -0.000001  0.186630  0.202067  0.179965 -0.000001
  0C   1px        0.000000  0.000001  0.140077 -0.259193  0.145762 -0.000001
  0C   1py        0.000000  0.000001 -0.231511  0.006068  0.233270  0.000002
  0C   2pz       -0.000000 -0.000000  0.132092  0.143018  0.127376  0.000000

(..................................)

  3H   1px       -0.000743  0.004220  0.008142 -0.000711  0.009734 -0.013234
  3H   1py        0.000254 -0.001445 -0.009341 -0.002708  0.006778  0.004530
  4H   1s        -0.000618  0.084595  0.047761  0.003667 -0.177787  0.014571
  4H   2s        -0.002140  0.091035  0.068203  0.005237 -0.253883 -0.128755
  4H   3s        -0.004359  0.012693  0.030427  0.002337 -0.113264  1.677382
  4H   1pz       -0.000823  0.004673  0.009583  0.007438 -0.004446 -0.014654
  4H   1px       -0.000743  0.004220  0.007638 -0.009051 -0.004613 -0.013233
  4H   1py       -0.001934  0.010983 -0.001402  0.000744 -0.017221 -0.034441
                      6         7         8         9        10        11   
                   0.12537   0.12537   0.12537   0.19934   0.19934   0.19934
                   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
                  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------
  0C   1s         0.000000  0.000001 -0.000000  0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000
  0C   2s         0.000000  0.000001 -0.000001 -0.000000 -0.000001 -0.000001
  0C   3s         0.000001  0.000002  0.000000  0.000001 -0.000003 -0.000004
  0C   4s        -0.000016 -0.000028  0.000006 -0.000000  0.000022  0.000024
  0C   5s         0.000073  0.000101  0.000018  0.000027 -0.000091 -0.000092
  0C   1pz        0.146975 -0.159982 -0.096223  0.083398 -0.072907  0.070651
  0C   1px        0.064477  0.158428 -0.164919  0.067754  0.108060  0.031535
(and so on)
```

My intention is to parse some of this cool information and perform operations with it, but the data is quite complex (looking at the first column):

- 0C is the first atom (carbon)
- (1, 2, 3,...)s, (1, 2, 3,...)p, etc are the atomic orbitals

  0    (Molecular orbital #)

-10.15161 (Energy of the orbital)

2.00000 (Occupation of the orbital)

So, my question is: what is the best and more efficient way to grab this from my output? Is there a Python module best suited for the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by reading your nicely formatted data into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
data = pd.read_fwf('data.txt', skiprows=3, widths=[7,10,10,10,10,10,10,10])
```

Remove the dashed lines:

```
data = data[data['0']!='--------']
```

Convert the strings to numbers:

```
data.iloc[:,2:] = data.iloc[:,2:].astype(float)
```

Remove white spaces from the first two columns:

```
data.iloc[:,:2] = data.iloc[:,:2].replace(' ', '')
```

Now, you can use the table. Just remember that it consists of several stacked blocks (you can recognize them by NaNs in the first column) that have to be unstacked and placed side by side.

Comment: Thank you so much, @DYZ, that was right in the spot!